# Jboss missing dependencies ojdbc

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I'm a true beginner with java and jboss but for my work i need to deploy a project on my jboss standalone server.
I solved tons and tons of error but i come to a stop with this one, i can't find a way to solve it this time...
Thanks for your help !

Console at server start :

```
09:25:50,149 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final-redhat-1
09:25:52,422 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.1.5.Final-redhat-1
09:25:52,849 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) démarre
09:26:03,063 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Pilotage.ear trouvé dans le répertoire du déploiement. Pour déclencher le déploiement, créer un fichier nommé Pilotage.ear.dodeploy
09:26:03,158 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO Version 3.0.10.GA-redhat-1
09:26:03,162 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Création d'un service de gestion http à l'aide de socket-binding (management-http)
09:26:03,199 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.10.GA-redhat-1
09:26:03,534 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS010153: Propriété d'identificateur de noeud définie à la valeur par défaut. Veillez à ce que cette valeur soit bien unique.
09:26:03,549 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS010280: Activation du sous-système Infinispan
09:26:03,558 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) JBAS012605: A activé les implémentations JSF suivantes : [main, 1.2]
09:26:03,612 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS015537: Activation de l'extension WebServices
09:26:03,628 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) JBAS013171: Activation du sous-système de sécurité
09:26:03,720 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010408: Démarrage du sous-système JCA (IronJacamar 1.0.26.Final-redhat-1)
09:26:03,724 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS013170: Version PicketBox actuelle=4.0.19.SP8-redhat-1
09:26:03,757 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS011800: Démarrage du sous-système de nommage
09:26:06,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS010404: Déploiement du pilote non compatible JDCB class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
09:26:06,219 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011802: Démarrage du service de nommage
09:26:06,220 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Session Mail liée [java:jboss/mail/Default]
09:26:06,314 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
09:26:06,327 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
09:26:06,673 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Source de données liée [java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDSParametre]
09:26:06,674 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010400: Source de données liée [java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDSPilotage]
09:26:07,241 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Remoting version (unknown)
09:26:08,723 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS010403: Déploiement du pilote compatible JDCB class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver (version 12.1)
09:26:10,531 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Lancement du déploiement de "Pilotage.ear" (runtime-name: "Pilotage.ear")
09:26:10,531 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015876: Lancement du déploiement de "struts.xml" (runtime-name: "struts.xml")
09:26:10,535 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Lancement du déploiement de "src" (runtime-name: "src")
09:26:10,697 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015012: FileSystemDeploymentService démarré pour le répertoire C:\Users\tdecobecq\EAP-6.3.0\jboss-eap-6.3\standalone\deployments
09:26:10,776 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017100: Écoute sur 127.0.0.1:9999
09:26:10,776 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Écoute sur 127.0.0.1:4447
09:26:12,812 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Lancement du déploiement de "null" (runtime-name: "Pilotage_web.war")
09:26:13,069 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3.0.Final-redhat-3
09:26:19,315 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Déploiement de "src" (runtime-name: "src")
09:26:19,316 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Déploiement de "struts.xml" (runtime-name: "struts.xml")
09:26:19,317 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Déploiement de "Pilotage.ear" (runtime-name: "Pilotage.ear")
09:26:19,321 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Rapport de statut de service
JBAS014775: Nouvelles dépendances manquantes/non complétées :
Dépendances service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.OracleDSBBr (manquantes) : [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.Pilotage.Pilotage_web.env.OracleDSBBr]

09:26:19,393 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: L'interface de gestion http écoute sur http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
09:26:19,425 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: La console d'administration écoute sur http://127.0.0.1:9990
09:26:19,426 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) a démarré (avec des erreurs) en 33059ms - 361 des services 498 démarré(s) (98 services ont échoué ou manquent de dépendances, 65 services sont lents, passifs ou à la demande)
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.oracle">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc7.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

standalone.xml

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.6">

    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
        and some others deleted due to so anti spam
    </extensions>


    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                    <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization>
                    <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <audit-log>
            <formatters>
                <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
            </formatters>
            <handlers>
                <file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </handlers>
            <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="file"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
        </audit-log>
        <management-interfaces>
            <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
            </native-interface>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
        <access-control provider="simple">
            <role-mapping>
                <role name="SuperUser">
                    <include>
                        <user name="$local"/>
                    </include>
                </role>
            </role-mapping>
        </access-control>
    </management>

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.4">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDSPilotage" pool-name="MysqlDSPilotage" enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/epi?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>15</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>1000</max-pool-size>
                        <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>!username!</user-name>
                        <password>!motdepasse!</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT *</check-valid-connection-sql>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDSParametre" pool-name="MysqlDSParametre" enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/parametre</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>15</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>1000</max-pool-size>
                        <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>!username!</user-name>
                        <password>!motdepasse!</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT *</check-valid-connection-sql>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle">
                        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.2">
            <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true</jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <annotation-property-replacement>false</annotation-property-replacement>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.4">
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </stateless>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>
                <cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/>
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <file-passivation-store name="file"/>
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default">
                <data-store path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="10"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
            <default-security-domain value="other"/>
            <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.5">
            <cache-container name="web" aliases="standard-session-cache" default-cache="local-web" module="org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan">
                <local-cache name="local-web" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
            <expose-resolved-model/>
            <expose-expression-model/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
            <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.1">
            <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
            </mail-session>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.4">
            <remote-naming/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1">
            <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.5">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
            <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
            <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>
    </profile>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>

</server>
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.mysql"/>
            <module name="com.oracle"/>
            and some others deleted due to stack overflow's anti spam
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.joda.time" slot="main"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="Pilotage_web.war">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.joda.time" slot="main"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.mysql"/>
            <module name="com.oracle"/>
            and some others deleted due to stack overflow's anti spam
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: I see the Oracle JDBC driver setup correctly but I don't see any datasources configured to use it. I see only MySQL datasources configured.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that if i don't put the oracle driver, i got exceptions : modulenofound com.oracle. I also don't understand why there is a need for the oracle driver, is there any way to clear this error without creating an oracle ds or creating easily an "empty" one ? Thank you for responding